SWIG Hello World; ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function
This is supposed to be the absolute minimum Hello World using SWIG, C, and setuptools. But the following exception is raised when the module is imported:
>>> import hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<python-input-0>", line 1, in <module>
    import hello
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_hello)

This is the directory structure:
README.md
pyproject.toml
src
src/hc
src/hc/hello.c
src/hc/hello.i

Here is the pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=75.6"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "helloc"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
    { name = "Foo" }
]
description = "Hello world SWIG C"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.13"
classifiers = [
    "Development Status :: 1 - Planning",
    "License :: Public Domain",
    "Natural Language :: English",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.13"
]

[tool.setuptools]
ext-modules = [
  { name = "hello", sources = ["src/hc/hello.c", "src/hc/hello.i"] }
]

Here is hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

void say_hello() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}

And here is the interface file:
%module hello

%{
void say_hello();
%}

void say_hello();


ext-modules = [{ name = "_hello",... (_hello)?

That worked! Please make that into an answer! I will vote it.

You don't need to, but if you can explain what happened, that would be awesome as well.

Your extension module should be named _hello (notice the leading "_").
pyproject.toml:
# ...

[tool.setuptools]
ext-modules = [
  { name = "_hello", sources = ["src/hc/hello.c", "src/hc/hello.i"] }
]

Check:

[SO]: c program SWIG to python gives 'ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function' (@CristiFati's answer) contains the SWIG related details

[SO]: How to solve Python-C-API error "This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip."? (@CristiFati's answer) contains info about building with SetupTools


